# Из опыта/по опыту

Tags: грамотная-речь

Добрый день.
Как правильно говорить:

Говорю вам из опыта:...
Говорю вам по опыту:...

Или верен какой-то другой вариант ответа?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, лучше будет сказать "сужу по собственному опыту".

Answer (score 1):

Вариант "из опыта" тоже возможен, но уже в несколько иной интерпретации, - например: "Откуда мне это известно? Да из собственного опыта!"

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал "говорю вам на основании собственного опыта".

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "говорю вам из  опыта".